# How to count values of a column of the same type in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables and after doing some joinings I've come to the stage where I'm trying to count the number of times a value of the same type (1 & 2) occurs in a column (column id) but I'm not sure how to create the query. Help?

```
  parent_id  id
    1        1
    1        1
    2        2
    1        1
    1        1
    1        1
```

In the id table, number "1" occurred 5 times and "2" 1 time. How can I create the query that resulted in a new column (maybe 2 columns for each) to show that "1" occurs 5 times and "2" occurs 1 time? This is the queries from the 3 original tables that led me to the id table.

```
SELECT parent_id, pods.id
FROM visits
JOIN parents
ON parents.id = visits.parent_id
JOIN pods
ON parents.pod_id = pods.id
```

I'm trying to get two columns: column 1 with the total number of "1" which is 5 and column 2 with the total number of "2" which is 1.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: some sample input and output needed to answer your question.

Comment: Your query returns two columns, but your example results have only one column.  That is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just looking for `group by`?

```
SELECT po.id, COUNT(*)
FROM visits v JOIN
     parents p
     ON p.id = v.parent_id JOIN
     pods po
     ON p.pod_id = po.id
GROUP BY po.id;
```

Comment: OMG! YES this is what I'm looking for, thank you soo much! I've been trying to figure this out all day long. #beginnerstruggle